# When exporting Google sheets to PDF how do I access the parameters

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

What I want to do is export a Google sheet as a PDF without it displaying the gridlines. I see code samples online of how to access that parameter when using a url like this:

```
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ssID+"/export"+
                                                        "?format=pdf&"+
                                                        "size=0&"+
                                                        "fzr=true&"+
                                                        "portrait=false&"+
                                                        "fitw=true&"+
                                                        "gridlines=false&"+
                                                        "printtitle=true&"+
                                                        "sheetnames=true&"+
                                                        "pagenum=CENTER&"+
                                                        "attachment=true";
```

But I am using the following code which does not utilitize a url:

```
       private static void DownloadfileFromGDrive(DriveService service, string fileId, string filePath)
       {
           var request = service.Files.Export(fileId, "application/pdf");

           using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
           {
               request.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged += (IDownloadProgress progress) =>
               {
                   switch (progress.Status)
                   {
                       case DownloadStatus.Downloading:
                           Debug.WriteLine(progress.BytesDownloaded);
                           break;
                       case DownloadStatus.Completed:
                           Debug.WriteLine("Download Complete");
                           break;
                       case DownloadStatus.Failed:
                           Debug.WriteLine("Download Failed");
                           break;
                   }
               };

               request.Download(memoryStream);

               using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
               {
                   fileStream.Write(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, memoryStream.GetBuffer().Length);
               };
           }
       }
```

How can I access those parameters from my code?

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Thank for your answer. And for following up. I thought I had responded. Sorry about that. It took a bit to figure it out but I was able to change my code to using the endpoint you provided. I wish there was a way to share my code. These comments don't allow for enough characters to post it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. If you have the final script for your question, you can add it to your question. By this, other users can see it. It will be useful for the users. By the way, I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this answer?

When the query parameter for exporting as the PDF format is used, unfortunately, `service.Files.Export(fileId, "application/pdf")` cannot be used for this situation. In this case, it is required to download the PDF file using the access token. The endpoint for this situation is as follows.

#### Endpoint:

```
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ssID+"/export"+
                                                      "?format=pdf&"+
                                                      "size=0&"+
                                                      "fzr=true&"+
                                                      "portrait=false&"+
                                                      "fitw=true&"+
                                                      "gridlines=false&"+
                                                      "printtitle=true&"+
                                                      "sheetnames=true&"+
                                                      "pagenum=CENTER&"+
                                                      "attachment=true&"+
                                                      "access_token=###"; // Added
```

- When you request this endpoint as GET method, the PDF data, which reflected the query parameter, can be retrieved.
- Of course, you can also add the access token to the request header instead of the query parameter.

#### Reference:

- [Standard Query Parameters](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/query-parameters)

If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.